# Show current email address in Mutt status line

Tags: mutt

I have multiple email accounts configured with Mutt, however it's not always clear to me in which account I'm currently on.

I'm looking forward to add my current email address (from the `from` property) in Mutt status line, however `status_format` doesn't document such sequence.

Is this possible?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264814/adjusting-colors-for-mutts-status-line-in-multi-account-setup. It is very useful to recognise different accounts, quickly, via different color settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments from Nikos is a good reference. I think what you need to do is to add `$from` into the `status_format` field.

It seems that mutt reads muttrc sequentially, which means you need to put the `set status_format=...` **after the** `set from=...` in order to make it work. If you make sure the `$from` is correctly set every time you change the account, the status line should be correctly displayed.