# Adjusting colors for mutt's status line in multi-account setup

Tags: colors, mutt

**Question**

How can mutt be configured correctly so, no matter the number of accounts it handles, color settings can be adjusted per account along with the folder-hooks?

**Details**

In a *mutt* multi-account setup, using account-hooks, in a file (below) which is sourced inside `muttrc`

```
# Account Hooks

# clean first
account-hook . 'unset imap_user; unset imap_pass; unset tunnel'

# account one
account-hook domain.net "set imap_user=id@domain.net imap_pass=${my_password}"

# account two
account-hook outlook.xyz.ch "set imap_user=id@xyz.ch imap_pass=${my_pastwo}"

# account three
account-hook mail.domain.ch "set imap_user=id@domain.ch imap_pass=${my_passthree}"
```

and the corresponding file-hooks, a file (below) which is also sourced inside `.muttrc`

```
# Folders and hooks

# domain.net
folder-hook 'domain.net' 'source ~/.mutt/domain.net'

# xyz
folder-hook 'outlook.xyz.ch' 'source ~/.mutt/outlook.xyz.ch'

# domain.ch
folder-hook 'mail.domain.ch' 'source ~/.mutt/domain.ch'

# source "default" on startup
source ~/.mutt/domain.net
```

the following set of entries, each set in a separate file (one file for each account), are instructions to adjust the color of mutt's status line:

File 1

```
# ~/.mutt/account.one
set hostname="mail.domain.net"
color status color144 color234
..
```

File 2

```
# ~/.mutt/account.two
set hostname = "outlook.xyz.ch"
color status brightyellow magenta
..
```

File 3

```
# .mutt/account.three
set hostname="mail.domain.ch"
color status cyan brightblue
..
```

- When launching mutt, the colors are set correctly (for the default account). [image]
- Switching to another account, i.e., the second or the third, works also correctly in setting the requested colors. In the following screenshot, account two has been selected. [image]
- After this, switching to the third or the second account, does not work. The following screenshot is of account three, after having visited, already once, account two [image] while, when visiting account three directly after launching mutt (and, thus, switching for the first time from the default account to another one) looks like the in the following snapshot. [image]
- For the sake of completeness, the following screenshot is of account two after having visited account three. [image]

The colors kept "in-memory" are *only* the first set (from the default account) and then, the second set -- i.e. one of either the second or the third account depending on which was selected to switch to.

I work with Funtoo-Linux and there is a note, in the default `muttrc` configuration file (see complete file copy-pasted below), which reads:

```
# ...For example, it is
# *impossible* currently in mutt to remove color settings from objects
# other than the index.
```

**Question** Is this note (above), the answer to the "problem" I describe?  Or, can this be configured correctly so, no matter the number of accounts mutt handles, the color settings can be changes as to any pre-set preference along with the folder-hooks?

---

Idea for per-account status-line-coloring sourced from: https://pbrisbin.com/posts/two_accounts_in_mutt/

**Current `muttrc`:**

```
# Some minimal Mutt settings, Gentoo-style.  These reflect the Gentoo
# predilection for maildir folders.
#
# Please don't add settings to this file to change other user
# preferences (such as colors), since those can be hard for a user to
# undo if their preference doesn't match yours!  For example, it is
# *impossible* currently in mutt to remove color settings from objects
# other than the index.


# Identity
set realname = 'Nikos Alexandris'

#set signature = ~/.mutt/signature

    # see account-hooks


# Receiving & Sending

    # see account- and/or folder-hooks

# tell the world what version of mutt I use
set user_agent


# respond using name they were sent to, if it's one of my addresses
# set reverse_name=yes

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Security
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

source "gpg2 --decrypt ~/.mutt/passwords.gpg |" # (options: --batch --use-agent -q --no-tty)

# also, see gpg file

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Paths
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# set folder="~/.offlineimap"           # see "folder_hooks" file
set header_cache = ~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir = ~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file = ~/.mutt/certificates

# set postponed = "~/.mutt/mail/postponed"# see account- & folder-hooks
# set record = "~/.mutt/mail/sent"        # see account- & folder-hooks

set mailcap_path = ~/.mutt/mailcap # entries for filetypes
set tmpdir = ~/.mutt/tmp           # where to keep temp files
    # -- conflicts, I fear, with .secret/.tmp -- see above

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Further customisations
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

# set imap_passive=no
set imap_authenticators='login'
set imap_keepalive=120
set imap_check_subscribed

ignore "Authentication-Results:"
ignore "DoaminKey-Signature:"
ignore "DKIM-Signature:"

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration variables
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

set abort_nosubject = yes
set abort_unmodified = yes
set query_command = "abook --mutt-query '%s'"

set hidden_host                           # Hide host details.

set assumed_charset = "utf-8"
set attach_charset = "utf-8"
set charset = "utf-8"

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Aliases
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

set alias_file = "~/.mutt/mutt-alias"
set alias_format = "%4n %t %a %r"
set sort_alias = alias
set reverse_alias = yes
source $alias_file

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Basic Options
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

#set wait_key = no      # silence, mutt
set sleep_time = 0
set mbox_type = Maildir # mailbox type
set timeout = 3         # idle time before scanning
set mail_check = 60     # minimum time between scans

#unset move             # gmail does that
#set delete             # don't ask, just do
set delete = ask-yes        # Ask before doing a delete.
#unset confirmappend    # don't ask, just do!
set noconfirmappend     # Just append, don't hassle me.
set quit                # don't ask, just do!!
#unset mark_old         # read/new is good enough for me
set nomark_old          # Don't mark unread new msgs as old.

set beep_new            # bell on new mails
set nobeep
set pipe_decode         # strip headers and eval mimes when piping
set thorough_search     # strip headers and eval mimes before searching

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Index View Options
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

set date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %T"
set index_format = "%2C | %Z [%d] %-30.30F (%-4.4c) %s"
set uncollapse_jump                        # don't collapse on an unread message

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Sorting
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

set smart_wrap = yes
set sort = 'threads'
set duplicate_threads = yes
set sort_aux = 'reverse-last-date-received' # =date-received OR last-date-received
set sort_re                                # thread based on regex
set reply_regexp = "^(([Rr][Ee]?(\[[0-9]+\])?: *)?(\[[^]]+\] *)?)*" # "^(re([\[0-9\]+])*|betr):[ \t]*"

set help = yes

set attribution = "* %n <%a> [%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z}]:\n"
set editor = 'vim + -c "set textwidth=72" -c "set wrap" -c "set nocp" -c "?^$" -c "set spell spelllang=en,de,fr,el" '

set reply_to = yes
set include = yes
set forward_quote = yes

# set imap_idle=yes # seems deprecated! http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html
set imap_peek = yes
set imap_servernoise = no

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Menu Options
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

set status_on_top # Status bar on top.
set menu_move_off = no
set menu_scroll = no
set mime_forward = ask-no

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Pager View Options
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

set pager_index_lines = 11  # number of index lines to show
set pager_context = 6       # Retain 6 lines of previous page when scrolling.
set pager_stop              # don't go to next message automatically
set menu_scroll             # scroll in menus
set tilde                   # show tildes like in vim

set read_inc = 100            # Read counter ticks every 100 msgs.
set write_inc = 100           # Write counter ticks every 100 msgs.

# set markers # mark wrapped lines of text in the pager with a +
unset markers               # no ugly plus signs

set quote_regexp = "^( {0,4}[>|:#%]| {0,4}[a-z0-9]+[>|]+)+"
alternative_order text/plain text/enriched text/html

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Header Options
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

set edit_headers = yes
ignore *                                # ignore all headers
unignore subject: from: to: cc: date:   # show only these
unhdr_order *                           # some distros order things by default
hdr_order subject: from: to: cc: date:  # and in this order

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# muttprint for printing
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

set print = ask-yes     # Ask before printing.
set print_command = "muttprint"

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Automatically process html mails
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

auto_view text/html

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Greek support -- Should read Hellenic!
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

# set charset="greek"
# set locale="el_GR"
# set send_charset="US-ASCII:ISO-8859-1:ISO-8859-7:UTF-8"

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Other configuration files
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

source ~/.mutt/account_hooks
source ~/.mutt/folder_hooks
source ~/.mutt/colors
source ~/.mutt/sidebar
source ~/.mutt/statusbar
source ~/.mutt/gpg
source ~/.mutt/macros
source ~/.mutt/lists

# Last, but not least, get mutt to display its version on startup.
push <show-version>
```

**Currently sourced color scheme:**

```
# Screenshot http://trovao.droplinegnome.org/stuff/mutt-zenburnt.png
#
# This is a zenburn-based mutt color scheme that is not (even by far)
# complete. There's no copyright involved. Do whatever you want with it.
# Just be aware that I won't be held responsible if the current color-scheme
# explodes your mail client. ;)
#
# Do notice that this color scheme requires a terminal emulator that supports
# 256 color. Any modern X terminal emulator should have support for that and
# you can enable it by calling mutt as "TERM=xterm-256color mutt" or, if you
# use screen, by adding "term screen-256color" to your .screenrc.
#
# This file is in the public domain.
#

# general-doesn't-fit stuff
color normal color188 color237
#color error color115 color236
color error color236 color210
color markers color142 color238
color tilde color108 color237
# color status color144 color234 # check in folder-hooks!

# index stuff
#color indicator color229 color238
color indicator color236 color188
color tree color109 color237
color index color188 color237 ~A
color index color228 color237 ~N # New
color index color174 color237 ~F # Flagged
color index color223 color237 ~O # Old
color index color108 color237 ~P # From me
color index color210 color237 ~D # Deleted

# header stuff
color hdrdefault color223 color237
color header color223 color237 "^Subject"

# gpg stuff
color body color188 color237 "^gpg: Good signature.*"
color body color115 color236 "^gpg: BAD signature.*"
color body color174 color237 "^gpg: Can't check signature.*"
color body color174 color237 "^-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----"
color body color174 color237 "^-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----"
color body color174 color237 "^-----END PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----"
color body color174 color237 "^-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----"
color body color174 color237 "^Version: GnuPG.*"
color body color174 color237 "^Comment: .*"

# url, email and web stuff
color body color174 color237 "(finger|ftp|http|https|news|telnet)://[^ >]*"
color body color174 color237 "<URL:[^ ]*>"
color body color174 color237 "www\\.[-.a-z0-9]+\\.[a-z][a-z][a-z]?([-_./~a-z0-9]+)?"
color body color174 color237 "mailto: *[^ ]+\(\\i?subject=[^ ]+\)?"
color body color174 color237 "[-a-z_0-9.%$]+@[-a-z_0-9.]+\\.[-a-z][-a-z]+"

# misc body stuff
color attachment color174 color237 #Add-ons to the message
color signature color223 color237

# quote levels
color quoted color108 color237
color quoted1 color116 color237
color quoted2 color247 color237
color quoted3 color108 color237
color quoted4 color116 color237
color quoted5 color247 color237
color quoted6 color108 color237
color quoted7 color116 color237
color quoted8 color247 color237
color quoted9 color108 color237

# vim: set ft=muttrc
```

Comment: My different accounts have individual colours and they work fine (based on Pat's sterling work). I suspect there is something in your `muttrc` is borking it...

Comment: @jasonwryan Question updated with complete `muttrc` and current colorscheme instructions.